# Is there a way to parallelize running R script by input files?

Tags: r, csv, parallel-processing, data-wrangling, doparallel

I'm reading in a bunch of files (over seven thousand) as data frames. All the files are in the same parent folder, with organized and consistent sub-directories. The files are currently organized by timestamp. I want to read the files in, and then export the files to a different folder, where each file is a player ID. There may be multiple timestamps for a single player in the same input data frame. And sometimes a player ID will not be in an input data frame at all. I've figured out the data wrangling (it's quite simple), but since each file is ~1.5 million rows it takes about 5 hours for a single file. So I can't simply loop through all seven thousand files. I want to parallelize by input file instead (though parallelizing by output file might be better?). I'll run this on an HPC with enough CPUs and I don't need to specify my CPU requirement before I use the HPC. I know the doParallel package exists, but the tutorial introduction `vignette("gettingstartedParallel")` didn't work and I didn't understand the other doParallel posts. (Please don't just refer me to the doParallel package without the relevant code.) I'm also concerned about the code crashing as it tries to write to the same csv multiple times. CSVs can't be written to in parallel, even if I set `append = TRUE`. Here's the code with how I read in the files and how I wrangle and write out the files to a new folder.

```
# Example input data frames (in the real code I create a vector of Alltimes using list.files() )
times1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c('PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL2','PL1'),
  times = c(42.6, 41.5, 42.9, 47.0, 44.3),
  speed = c(64, 66, 43, 39, 55) 
)

times2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c('PL3', 'PL3', 'PL3', 'PL1','PL1'),
  times   = c(62.1, 51.7, 65.9, 62.1, 55.3),
  speed = c(71, 73, 45, 64, 66) 
)

# Create vector of all parquets filepaths
Alltimes <- list.files(path = 'Input_Folder_Path)',
                       pattern = '*.snappy.parquet$',
                       recursive = TRUE,
                       full.names = TRUE)

# Iterate through timestamp input files (I want this part parallelized instead of a loop)
# for( i in 1:length(Alltimes)){
  
  # Read in the individual file
  # when the Alltimes vector is the file path I use read_parquet( Alltimes[i] ), but
  # times1 is a substitute for this example.
  df = times1 
  # df = times2
  # df = read_parquet( Alltimes[i] )
  
  # get vector of all player ids in this data frame
  all_ids_vec <- unique(x = df$ID)
  
  # write out individual csv for each player ID
  for(j in 1:length(all_ids_vec)){
    
    # Subset the df by that specific player ID
    one_player <- df %>% filter(ID == all_ids_vec[j])
    
    write.table(x = one_player, 
                file = "C:/Users/Juliet/Desktop/", all_ids_vec[j],".csv", 
                append = TRUE, 
                quote = FALSE, 
                sep = ",", 
                row.names = FALSE, 
                col.names = FALSE)
  }
# }
```

Comment: If *"each file is a player ID"* then why `unique(x = df$ID)`?

Comment: I want each ```OutputFile.csv``` to be a player ID. each ```InputFile.csv``` has many different player IDs in it

Comment: OK, so it's probably better to `split` by `ID` and process each at a time. Now what I don't understand is why it takes 5hrs to process 1.5M rows, most of the time must be going to data wrangling, right?

Comment: The data wrangling goes pretty fast. I think it's the writing out to separate csvs that takes so long. There are ~1.5 million rows and ~500K unique IDs per file. So I'm writing out ~500K csvs, and each has 3 rows in it, for every input file (these numbers are approximate and not consistent across input files. Though each input file has about the same number of rows). I think it's taking a long time because I run out of RAM and I'm testing this on my local computer. But when I process everything it will be on an HPC and I can allocate more RAM. What's the code to ```split``` by ```ID```?

Comment: The code to split by id is `df_split <- split(df, df$ID)`. Then you can process each of them with `lapply`. This is faster than to filter one by one, assign to a new data.frame and save it. You can avoid this filter and assignment altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I should have specified: I'm testing the code on a Windows device but I'll be running it on an Ubuntu linux HPC. Will the same code work, minus the ```detectCores``` function?

Comment: Yes, it will. Actually, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and there were no problems. The main difference is that only sockets work Windows (they work on any system). Whereas forking works on POSIX systems but not on Windows.

Comment: I've timed it and the parallel version with 3 cores only took under 0.5 secs, the serial (`lapply`) took nearly 10 secs. There was a speed up by a factor of 30. To process all 7000 files would take around 48h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the files to disk in parallel, the following code works on Windows. Note that package `doParallel` is not meant for Windows.

```
library(parallel)

dirname <- "C:/Users/611913/Desktop"
#dirname <- path.expand("~/tmp/so")

sp <- split(df, df$ID)
id_vec <- names(sp)

f <- function(X, filename, path){
  filename <- file.path(path, filename)
  write.table(x = X, 
              file = filename, 
              append = TRUE, 
              quote = FALSE, 
              sep = ",", 
              row.names = FALSE, 
              col.names = FALSE)  
}

# Windows
ncores <- detectCores()

cl <- makeCluster(ncores - 1L)
clusterExport(cl, "sp")
clusterExport(cl, "id_vec")
clusterExport(cl, "dirname")
clusterExport(cl, "f")

clusterEvalQ(cl, "sp")
clusterEvalQ(cl, "id_vec")
clusterEvalQ(cl, "dirname")
clusterEvalQ(cl, "f")

res <- parLapply(cl, seq_along(sp), function(j){
  f(sp[[j]], id_vec[j], dirname)
})

stopCluster(cl)
```

---

### Test data

This code creates the test data.

```
n <- 1000L
ID <- sprintf("id%04d", seq_len(n))
ID <- rep(ID, 3)
df <- data.frame(ID, x = rnorm(3*n), y = sample(10, 3*n, TRUE))
```